# Drop lowest input from Array?

Tags: c++

I have to find the lowest input given, then average out the total minus the lowest score. I am having a bit of trouble with my `averageScore` function finding the lowest score from the array. I am getting very odd numbers as my output. Any suggestions on how to adjust this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
double* allocate(int&);
double averageScore(int&);

int main()
{   
    double* testArray;
        int numOfScores;
    double average;

    testArray = allocate(numOfScores);
    average = averageScore(numOfScores);

    //delete memory created
    delete[] testArray;

    return 0;
}

//function to collect user info, dynamically allocate
double* allocate(int &numOfScores)
{
    double* testArray;

    //prompt user for scores
    cout << "How many test scores would\n";
    cout << "you like to process: ";

    //user input validation 
    if(!(cin >> numOfScores))
    {
        cout << "Invalid input!\n";
        cout << "Program termination, please\n";
        cout << "restart the program." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(numOfScores < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input!\n";
        cout << "Program termination, please\n";
        cout << "restart the program." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    //dynammically allocate an arrray to hold the scores
    testArray = new double[numOfScores];

    //get the scores from user
    for (int count = 0; count < numOfScores; count++)   
    {
        cout << "Enter Score: ";

        //user input validation 
        if(!(cin >> testArray[count]))
        {
            cout << "Invalid input!\n";
            cout << "Program termination, please\n";
            cout << "restart the program." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(testArray[count] < 0.0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid input!\n";
            cout << "Program termination, please\n";
            cout << "restart the program." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }


    }

    return testArray;
}

//function to calculate the average score
double averageScore(int &numOfScores)
{   
    double* testArray;

    double total,
           average,
           scores[0],
           lowest;

    lowest = scores[0];   

    //calculate total scores entered
    for(int count = 0; count < numOfScores; count++)
    {
        total += testArray[count];

        //find lowest score entered 
        for(int count = 1; count < numOfScores; count++)
        {
            if (testArray[numOfScores] < lowest)
                lowest = scores[numOfScores];
        }
    }

    //average the total amount of scores drop the lowest
    average = (total -  lowest) / numOfScores;

    cout << "The average test score is: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Lowest is: " << lowest << endl;

    return average;
}
```

Comment: two comments: use vectors instead of dynamically allocated arrays if you can, and there is no point to 'int &numOfScores' when you're not going to modify it, just pass it by value.

Comment: why are you doing `double averageScore(int &numOfScores)` instead of `double averageScore(int numOfScores)`?

Comment: You don't need the inner `for` loop to find the lowest value.  Just compare each `testArray[count]` value to `lowest` in your outer loop.

Comment: If you're removing one of the scores, you should divide by (numOfScores - 1) to reflect that. Also, you need to check for the special case in which there is only one score to avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: Also you create a local variable testArray but I can't find anywhere where you fill it.

Comment: This can be done without arrays, do you need to use arrays?

Comment: I must dynamically create an array for the scores. That is the only required array though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your `averageScore` function, but i'll cover the most basic one for now.

First off, you should pass it some sort of data.  Right now you're using `testArray` I don't even see where it is allocated.  I'm surprised that you're not getting segmentation faults when you run this.

But it's also not initialized.  In c++, when you declare a pointer, the variable it points to has a value.  It has a garbage value, and if you perform arithmetic operations with that garbage value, then your output will be garbage too.

You have to make your list of scores available to your `averageScore` function, preferably by passing them in as a parameter.

the beginning of your averaging function looks like the following:

```
double averageScore(int &numOfScores)
{   
    double* testArray;
    ...
```

instead it should look like this

```
double averageScore(double*testArray, int numOfScores)
{   
    ...
```

when you use `&numOfScores` instead of `numOfScores`, that means that if you change `numOfScores` in your `averageScore` function, than it will change in your `main` function as well, and you shouldn't do that.

now, on the `double* testArray;` line, you're declaring a brand new pointer, named "testArray", and there's no meaningful data in it, although it might be full of garbage.   there might be other double pointer variables, named "testArray" in your code, but none of them are in the scope of your `averageScore` function.  If you pass `testArray` in, in your method call, you'll then be able to use it.  for example: `double someNumber = testArray[i]`.

Bare in mind that your array is also being passed by reference.  If you would rather pass it by value, you can try

```
`double averageScore(double testArray[], int numOfScores)`
```

but don't quote me on that one

Once you've done that, your code will still have some issues, but the output should be meaningful enough that you'll hopefully be able to work those out on your own.

Comment: Thank you. I thought i was passing the list of scores to 'averageScore' as a parameter with '&numOfScores'

Comment: @Gmenfan83 `&numOfScores` is just a reference to a single interger, and it appears to be the count of the scores.  only making that available to your function is like asking a person "I have 5 numbers, can you find their average?"  
I'll edit my answer a bit to help you along

Comment: Than you @Sam I am very much to take the time out to explain this to me. It is much appreciated. I will soak this in a attempt to revise what's needs to be.

Comment: I seem to be having difficulties with passing function values and references and pointers.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<double> scores = {1.2,6.5,3.0,8.3,4.8,6,7.7};

// drop lowest score
scores.erase(min_element(begin(scores),end(scores)));

double average = accumulate(begin(scores),end(scores),0.0)/scores.size();
```

Comment: While this may be correct, my guess is that this is beyond the scope of the current course he is taking(note the homework tag) and would not be the approach to take on this.

Comment: you should probably add namespace specifiers, but like this answer, less is more! And favours the std lib

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to change this line:

```
if(testArray[numOfScores] < lowest)
```

to this:

```
if(testArray[count] < lowest)
```

Also, as @jzworkman points out, the denominator for averaging should be (numScores - 1) since you are eliminating the lowest score from the numerator. (If applicable, you might want to test for the edge case where there is only one score, which leaves nothing to average once you eliminate the lowest score.)

Answer (score 2):

Couple issues.  You shouldnt have those two for loops nested(instead just check if the value is lower than the lowest using an if statement).

Since this is homework I will give you the steps and then you can fix your code

1. Loop through and calculate the total, finding the lowest score at the same time
2. Calculate the average as (total-lowest)/(numScores -1)
3. Return the average

Comment: could you explain why i would do (total-lowest)/(numScores -1) rather (total - lowest)/ numOfScores? Thank you. I am just confused and want to learn. I know this is homework but i also want o be a programmer so it is important.

Comment: Because you are taking one of the values out of your total.  Imagine I have the following input: `1, 3, 5,` if I take out the lowest(1) then my average is `(3+5)/2` since I have two values that I am averaging.  You wouldnt want it to be `(3+5)/3` because after removing the lowest value you only have 2 values left, not 3